# Shell script that executes program with inputs

Tags: c++, linux, arguments

OK I'm trying to create a shell script that executes a program with an input that is a getline. However I'm running into a problem where I get the error 
Bash:

> syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

I don't know if it matters but the user input or in this case bash script is then broken up using the boost library tokenizer

Right now I'm trying in my script

```
echo "hello people" | ./a.out
```

Comment: Is that line your entire script?

Comment: `echo -n "hello people"` if `./a.out` is complaining about the newline added by `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` command by default adds a newline to the end of the string.
The newline might be causing the  `| ./a.out` to go to the next line, thereby causing the syntax error.

Try:

```
echo -n "hello people" | ./a.out
```

The `-n` option indicates to "not output the trailing newline".